# Submit button is running session validation instead

Tags: php, html

I have this page which when opened just reads in some session variables and assigns them to new variables and then unsets them, I do this so they can't be carried forward to another page. This all works good.

But, I also have a submit button with a form on the same page.  For some reason, when I press the submit button, it is not completing the queries it should and just reuses the session checking code. Which because the session variables are unset, then fails the validation for them.

Why is it re-running this session validation and not running my submit button code/

This is the session validation at the very top of the page, and is the code which for some reason is re-run on submit button click

```
$ahid="";
    $bid="";
    $np="";
    $nt="";

if (isset($_SESSION['ahid'])) {

          $ahid = $_SESSION['ahid'];
          unset($_SESSION['ahid']);
          if (isset($_SESSION['bid'])) {

                $bid = $_SESSION['bid'];
                unset($_SESSION['bid']);
                if (isset($_SESSION['nt'])) {

                        $nt = $_SESSION['nt'];
                        unset($_SESSION['nt']);
                        if (isset($_SESSION['np'])) {


                            $np = $_SESSION['np'];
                            unset($_SESSION['np']);
                         }else{
                                  header('Location: builders.php?hi=1');
                                  exit();
                              }
                 }else{
                          header('Location: builders.php?hi=2');
                          exit();
                      }
         }else{
                  header('Location: builders.php?hi=3');
                  exit();
              }
     }else{
              header('Location: builders.php?hi=4');
              exit();
          }
```

This is the submit button code that should be run, but instead is not even touched

```
if(isset($_POST['build_chk_finish'])){

        $construction_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO construction (user_id, estate_id, addon_h_id, builder_id, con_total_price, con_total_time, con_time_started, con_time_ending, con_completed) 
     VALUES('$user_id', '$estate_id', '$ahid', '$bid', '$np', '$nt', now(), '$future_date', '0')", $general)  
     or die (mysql_error());

     $construction_id = mysql_insert_id();

     $con_error="";
     $con_error = "Congratualtions! Your Builder has been hired and has begun work.";
            $_SESSION['error'] = $con_error;
            header("Location: houses.php");

    }
```

Just for added info, when I press the submit button it is failing on the first session validation `builders.php?hi=4`.

Here is the submit button

`<input name="build_chk_finish" type="submit" class="build_chk_finish" id="bc_submit"/>`

Comment: So, let me talk to you about SQL injection ..

Comment: @dbf Since this is only part of the script, how could you possibly be sure that the variables used in the query are not already properly escaped?

Comment: @Jocelyn, let me just say I have a very big feeling that those variables aren't escaped .. secondly, anybody with a little bit of knowledge would already have dumped the mysql_* ages ago ..

Comment: @dbf Agreed, the variables are likely not escaped. Only one way to be sure: ask the OP.

Comment: @Arken: If you are not using `mysql_real_escape_string` in your code, then you need to read [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I do plan on doing `mysql_real_escape_string` and everything else later, my main concern isn't that at the moment, it is just getting the main functionality of the site working first, and then worry about that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand, this brunch is executed:

```
}else{
        header('Location: builders.php?hi=4');
        exit();
}
```

When it should not, as I understand. But take a look at if branches. One above will be executed any time when $_SESSION['ahid'] is not set. That is because that else is related to `if (isset($_SESSION['ahid'])) {`:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['ahid'])) {
        ....// a lot of other if statements here
    }else{
            header('Location: builders.php?hi=4');
            exit();
    }
```